# Non US or Canada citizen travelling to Windsor through Windsor/Detroit tunnel on tunnel bus

Tags: international-travel, buses, canadian-residents, detroit, tunnels

I want to travel to Windsor using the Windsor/Detroit tunnel bus. I am a non-US-citizen from Pakistan. I read that I am 'required' to get back on the tunnel bus after customs but what if my customs clearance takes too long? I am fine with being left behind since I can ask a friend to pick me up on the Windsor side, but would I be in trouble legally if I am unable to make it back on the bus? I anticipate my customs to take long since I am performing my first landing as a new permanent resident to Canada.

Comment: Nice!  I suppose the CBSA people at the Windsor tunnel don't get a lot of first landings, especially not of people from outside North America.

Comment: It might be more cases than you think. People converting from other visas to PR are required to leave and re-enter Canada, and it's common to do it at a US land border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tunnel bus between Windsor and Detroit runs [frequently](https://www.citywindsor.ca/residents/transitwindsor/Routes-and-Schedules/Documents/fall-schedule/2015/tunnel.pdf).  If your clearance takes too long the bus will leave without you and you will take the next tunnel bus.  You will be shown where to wait in this case.

I've once departed a Greyhound bus exactly on the boundary crossing into New York state from Ontario, and took a taxi from the border to my destination.

Comment: Seems likely it's also possible to walk out to the street on the Canadian side with permission and supervision of the CBSA - the border station is in the middle of a downtown block in Windsor.